# Javascript - string.replace() text spanning multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Let's say I have text (not html), that I'm pulling from a textarea. It looks like:

```
ALTER LOGIN [user1] DISABLE 

GO 

~~~~~~~~~~~~~ important stuff to keep ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

~~~~~~~~~~~~~ important stuff to keep ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

~~~~~~~~~~~~~ important stuff to keep ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 


ALTER LOGIN [user2] DISABLE 

GO

~~~~~~~~~~~~~ important stuff to keep ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

~~~~~~~~~~~~~ important stuff to keep ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

~~~~~~~~~~~~~ important stuff to keep ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm trying to delete from ALTER to GO for each user. With replace(), I can replace from ALTER to DISABLE, but I can't quite figure out how to match all the way to GO (which is on the next line), so that it removes the whole chunk. Thoughts?

Comment: had you consider replacing the text using regular expressions?

Comment: I'm pretty horrible with regx's, definitely something I need to work on.  Thanks for the answer Alex!

Answer (score 21):

`.` in a regex matches every character *except* `\n`. In some regex flavours, you can add the `s` flag to make it match them, but not in Javascript.

Instead, you can use the `[\s\S]` character class, which matches all whitespace and all non whitespace, which is everything. The `?` after `*` means it won't be greedy, otherwise it will match between the first `ALTER` and the last `GO`.

```
str = str.replace(/ALTER[\s\S]*?GO/g, '');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7eTWE/).